# ¿como puedo pasar el script de sql server a un script funcional en mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, script

```
CREATE DATABASE chauquear 
GO
USE chauquear
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[area_ch](
    [idarea] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [nombre_area] [varchar](45) primary key NOT NULL default 'Sin Area',
    [fecha] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [estado] [varchar](45) NOT NULL
    )


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[centro_cultivo_ch](
    [idcc] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [nombre_CentroCultivo] [varchar](45) primary key NOT NULL default 'Sin Centro Cultivo',
    [fecha] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [estado] [varchar](45) NOT NULL,
    [nombre_area] [varchar](45) foreign key (nombre_area)
    references area_ch(nombre_area) 
    on delete set default
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    [codigo_decreto] [varchar](45) NOT NULL,
    [codigo_concesion] [varchar](45) NOT NULL,
    [total_linea] [int] NOT NULL,
    [monto_inicial] [int] NOT NULL,
    [creado] [int] NOT NUll)


    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[cuadrante_ch](
    [idcuadrante] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [nombre_cuadrante] [varchar](45) primary key NOT NULL default 'Sin Cuadrante',
    [total_linea] [int] NOT NULL,
    [monto_inicial] [int] NOT NULL,
    [creado] [int] NOT NUll,
    [fecha] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [nombre_area] [varchar](45) NOT NULL ,
    [nombre_CentroCultivo] [varchar](45)  foreign key (nombre_CentroCultivo)
    references centro_cultivo_ch(nombre_CentroCultivo) 
    on delete set default 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    [estado] [varchar](45) NOT NULL
    )

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[linea_ch](    
    [idlinea] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL ,
    [nombre_linea] [varchar] (45) NOT NULL primary key default 'Sin Linea' ,
    [fecha] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [estado] [varchar](45) NOT NULL,
    [TipoMaterial] [varchar](45) NOT NULL,
    [Observacion] [varchar](140) NOT NULL,
    [nombre_area] [varchar](45) NOT NULL,
    [nombre_CentroCultivo] [varchar](45) NOT NULL,
    [nombre_cuadrante] [varchar](45) foreign key (nombre_cuadrante)
    references cuadrante_ch(nombre_cuadrante) 
    on delete set default 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    [cantidad] int not null,
    total_cuelgas int not null,
    [stock_inicial] [int] NOT NULL,
    [creado] [int] NOT NUll
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BodegaSiembraSemillaColector_ch](    
    [idBodegaSiembraSemillaColector] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL ,
    [Codigo_Bodega] [varchar] (45) NOT NULL,
    [nombre_Bodega] [varchar] (45) NOT NULL primary key ,
    [fecha] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [estado] [varchar](45) NOT NULL,
    [Observacion] [varchar](140) NOT NULL,
    [nombre_area] [varchar](45) NOT NULL,
    [nombre_CentroCultivo] [varchar](45) NOT NULL,
    [nombre_cuadrante] [varchar](45)NOT NULL,
    [nombre_linea] [varchar] (45) foreign key (nombre_linea)
    references linea_ch(nombre_linea) 
    on delete set default 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    [Tipo_Semilla] [varchar] (45) NOT NULL,
    [cantidad_Semilla] int not null,
    total_cuelgas int not null,
    [stock_inicial] [int] NOT NULL,
    [creado] [int] NOT NUll,
    StockInicial_Semilla int NOT NULL,
    CreadoSemilla int not null  
)



    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NombreSiembra_ch](
    [idsiembra_SemillaColector] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FolioSiembraSemillaColector] [varchar](45) NOT NULL,
    [fecha] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [Nombre_SiembraSemillaColector] [varchar](45) NOT NULL primary key  default  'Sin Folio',
    [Presupuesto] int NOT NULL)

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[siembra_semillacolector_ch](
    [idsiembra_SemillaColector] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FolioSiembraSemillaColector] [varchar](45) NOT NULL  primary key  default  'Sin Folio',
    [nombre_area] [varchar](45) NOT NULL,
    [nombre_CentroCultivo] [varchar](45) NOT NULL,
    [nombre_cuadrante] [varchar](45) NOT NULL,
    [nombre_linea] [varchar] (45) foreign key (nombre_linea)
    references linea_ch(nombre_linea) 
    on delete set default 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    [fecha] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [Nombre_SiembraSemillaColector] [varchar](45) foreign key (Nombre_SiembraSemillaColector)
    references NombreSiembra_ch(Nombre_SiembraSemillaColector) 
    on delete set default 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    [origen_semilla] [varchar](45) NOT NULL,
    [numero_colectores] [int] NOT NULL,
    [numero_flotadores] [int] NOT NULL,
    [total_colectores] [int] NOT NULL,
    [talla_semilla] [varchar](45) NOT NULL,
    [peso_promedio] [int] NOT NULL,
    [destino] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Observacion] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [transporte] [int] NOT NULL,
    [cantidad] int not null,
    total_cuelgas int not null
    )

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[kardex_cuadrante](
[id_kardexCuadrante] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[nombre_area] [varchar](45) NOT NULL,
[nombre_CentroCultivo] [varchar](45) foreign key (nombre_CentroCultivo)
references centro_cultivo_ch(nombre_CentroCultivo) 
on delete CASCADE 
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
[nombre_cuadrante] [varchar](45) NOT NULL,
[monto_inicial] [int] NOT NULL,
[creado] [int] NOT NUll,
[total_linea] [int] NOT NULL,
[fecha] [datetime] NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[kardex_linea](
[id_kardexLinea] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[nombre_area] [varchar](45) NOT NULL,
[nombre_CentroCultivo] [varchar](45) NOT NULL,
[nombre_cuadrante] [varchar](45) foreign key (nombre_cuadrante)
references cuadrante_ch(nombre_cuadrante) 
on delete CASCADE 
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
[nombre_linea] [varchar] (45) NOT NULL,
[total_linea] [int] NOT NULL,
[monto_inicial] [int] NOT NULL,
[creado] [int] NOT NUll,
[fecha] [datetime] NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[kardex_cuelgas](
[id_kardexLinea] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[nombre_area] [varchar](45) NOT NULL,
[nombre_CentroCultivo] [varchar](45) NOT NULL,
[nombre_cuadrante] [varchar](45) NOT NULL,
[nombre_linea] [varchar] (45)  foreign key (nombre_linea)
references linea_ch(nombre_linea) 
on delete CASCADE 
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
[total_linea] [int] NOT NULL,
[monto_inicial] [int] NOT NULL,
[creado] [int] NOT NUll,
[fecha] [datetime] NOT NULL
)

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[usuarios](
    [id_usuarios] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL primary key,
    [Rut] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Nombre] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Apellidos] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](45) NOT NULL,
    [Cargo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Direccion] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Fecha_Nacimiento] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Telefono] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Ciudad] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Usuario] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [Contrasena] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL)

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[cargo](
    [idcargo] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL primary key,
    [Nombre_cargo] [varchar](45) NOT NULL)


    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[usuarios]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [usuarios$usuarios_ibfk_1] FOREIGN KEY([Cargo])
REFERENCES [dbo].[cargo] ([idcargo])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[cargo] ON
INSERT [dbo].[cargo] ([idcargo], [Nombre_cargo]) VALUES (1, N'Programador')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[cargo] OFF
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[usuarios] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[usuarios] ([id_usuarios], [Rut], [Nombre], [Apellidos], [Email], [Cargo], [Direccion], [Fecha_Nacimiento], [Telefono], [Ciudad], [Usuario], [Contrasena]) VALUES (1, N'18734602', N'Cristian', N'Jonhson Alvarez', N'cristian@mline.cl', 1, N'Puerto Montt', CAST(N'1994-04-22' AS Date), 89587246, N'Puerto Montt', N'cris', N'admin')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[usuarios] OFF
```

Comment: Hola JKonG, por favor lee [ask] y mejora tu pregunta :)

Comment: cual debe ser tu primary key? idarea o nombre_area? o los dos?

Comment: ES NOMBRE_AREA LA PRIMARY KEY

Comment: saludos @JKonG te sugiero que a tu pregunta le anexes la descripción de cada atributo de la tabla, como comentas de la primary key

Comment: saludos @alfredo no entiendo eso de anexar

Comment: puedes darle click en la opción justo debajo de tu pregunta "EDITAR" y agregar una descripción mas clara de tus columnas

Comment: Esto no tiene ningún sentido: `[nombre_area] [varchar](45) primary key NOT NULL default 'Sin Area'` ¿puedes explicar cómo sería posible tener un primary key que admita un valor por defecto? sólo funcionará la primera vez.

Comment: saludos @a cedeano eso mismo me pregunto ya que el script no es mio y en la empresa donde trabajo lo tienen implementado y con un software funcional :)

Answer (score 0):

Te comento lo siguiente:

1.- Tu código en MySQL debería quedar del modo siguiente

```
MySQL[social]> CREATE TABLE area_ch(
    -> idarea INT PRIMARY KEY  AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    -> nombre_area VARCHAR(45) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    -> INDEX(nombre_area),
    -> fecha DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    -> estado VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL);
```

`idarea` debería ser tu `PRIMARY KEY()`, toda vez que es el id con el que cada registro se guarda y te serviría después para usarlo tal vez como llave foránea en otra tabla con la que se pueda relacionar

con AUTO_INCREMENT se hace el incremento de un valor inicial

Haciendo un DESCRIBE de la tabla recién creada obtendremos una vista así

```
MySQL [social]> DESCRIBE area_ch;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| idarea      | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| nombre_area | varchar(45) | NO   | UNI | NULL                |                |
| fecha       | datetime    | NO   |     | current_timestamp() |                |
| estado      | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

Te comento que `nombre_area` no debería ser tu `PK` pues ese va a ser un valor único que me permita identificar a cada registro dado de alta; del mismo modo este registro único es el que me va a permitir usarlo como `FK` en otra tabla donde necesite tener relacionados los datos

---

`nombre_area` puede por el contrario tener el atributo de `UNIQUE` para que dicho valor no se repita así mismo almacenarlo como `INDEX` para usarlo de un modo optimizado al realizar búsquedas

Además que usar `nombre_area` como llave primaria un tipo de atributo que no se puede repetir limitaría en el paso del tiempo el propio ingreso de información

al menos en MySQL no puedes tener una columna como `primary key` que sea `auto_increment` y otra columna que sea primary key; pues `auto increments` solo puede estar presente una vez como `PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: gracias @alfredo de hecho igual me parece bastante raro que lo hallan hecho funcionar con su respectiva base de datos y aplicación

Comment: si igual haria falta indagar mas de la lógica que siguieron para tomar esa elección @JKonG igual espero que mi aporte te de una guía

Comment: no se si se podra subir el archivo completo como para que le hechen un vistazo y dar su opinion